# Does butter before drinking alcohol help with hangovers and getting too drunk?

Tags: alcohol

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does eating greasy foods 'help soak up alcohol'?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7152/does-eating-greasy-foods-help-soak-up-alcohol)

I've been told to always take a buttered sandwich prior to going out drinking because it would prevent me from getting "vomiting all over the place" drunk and from having a terrible hangover the next day.

I've stopped drinking, so I can't really test it out.

Comment: *I've stopped drinking*: is that because the butter trick didn't work? :D

Comment: I know a military chap who used to down a small glass of olive oil before going out for a big session as he reckoned it reduced the absorption of alcohol...he still used to get drunk, so ymmv

Comment: I don't have any paper to back this up, which is why this is a comment not an answer: a hangover corresponds to dehydration. In fact, your body needs to use up a lot of water to remove traces of the alcohol consumed. Vomiting is a sign that your alcohol intake is too high in a short period of time. I would see absolutely no correlation between eating butter and preventing alcohol poisoning and hangovers.

Comment: I've heard from bartenders that eating greasy foods help you to recover from drunkenness... I don't know where they got this information, though. And while it may be valid anecdotal evidence, I don't know many bartenders with PhDs to make a qualified claim.